Despliegue de proyecto php en Vercel
Buenas días / tardes / noches!
Estoy desarrollando un pequeño proyecto en php y lo estoy desplegando en vercel. Cuando cargo el proyecto en local o en un servidor web con administrador cpanel este funciona con normalidad. Pero cuando lo despliego en vercel, este no carga los ficheros css y js. he probado varias estructuras de ficheros siendo esta la que actualmente manejo:
├── /api
│   └── index.php
│
├── /public
│   ├── /assets
│   │   ├── /css
│   │   │   └── styles.css
│   │   └── /js
│   │       └── scripts.js
│   └── index.php 
├── /src
│   └── other-php-files.php
│
└── vercel.json

Donde, en mi fichero vercel.json uso el siguiente codigo para que pueda aplicar el runtime de php:


{
  "functions": {
    "api/index.php": {
      "runtime": "vercel-php@0.7.1"
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/api/index.php"
    }

  ]
}



Esto le indica a vercel que debe de abrir mi archivo index.php ubicado en la carpeta api.
Dentro de la carpeta api tenemos un index.php en el cual aplicamos una redirección al proyecto completo que esta ubicado en la carpeta /public con el siguiente codigo:
 require __DIR__ . '/../public/index.php';

El proyecto es un desarrollo tipico y simple de php (sin composer ni frameworks) donde se cargan los ficheros css y js en el index.php con url relaitivas teniendo dentro del head el llamado a los ficheros de la siguiente manera:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

Y el resultado obtenido es solo el contenido sin nada de estilos:

Pueden visualizar la web en Gabriel Yturrino
De ante mano se agradece cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.
Que tengan una buen día / tarde / noche!

Proba indicando el path absoluto, ejemplo: href="/assets/css/style.css"
